# imagestring creates blurry text?

Tags: php, gd

I am using imagestring to draw small sized text on top of my image. I use this to draw the text (`$radUrl`) and save the image (`$img`) to `$radPath`

```
imagestring($img, 3, 8, 8, $radUrl, imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 0, 0));
imagejpeg($img, $radPath, 100);
//($radUrl is a string, $radPath is the path to save the image)
```

The text it creates is blurry. It is too blurry to read. There is already some even smaller pre-existing text in the image which is sharp and easy to read.

Why is the text so blurred, and how can this problem be fixed?

**Edit:**
Using PNG images fixes this issue. However, in order to save bandwidth costs / processing power I must stick with `imagejpeg`. I know JPEG compression reduces the quality of everything especially lines / text, but all the other text in the image is fine.

In the image below the blurry red text at the top is the text created with `imagestring`, and the sharp white city names were already on the original image stored on my server's hard drive.

[image]

Comment: I would personally just try some debugging like change the output format from jpg to another format like png. Maybe change the font value or even load a different font using imageloadfont. If no luck after that, then maybe try removing the base image and see if text on a flat color background makes a difference.

Comment: imagepng fixes the blurry text problem. However, I need to be using imagejpeg as imagepng uses more processing power for PNG compression and creates larger files. My web app takes fairly large amounts of traffic and I have a tight budget for server costs.

Comment: Other than that, maybe use your own font using imageloadfont. Or just use png and cache the image. There is no reason to re-create the image every time if the base image and/or the text hasn't changed. If you know how often the base image changes (and I doubt it is realtime, everytime), then just write the url, save to disk and call the image on disk.

Comment: Also, how are you loading the base image? Maybe changing that to one like imagecreatetruecolor(). Maybe there is compression on the original image and that is being applied to the text on write then it is being uncompressed before output. Just guessing. If the url doesn't change, maybe save that as an image and imagecopymerge them together.

Comment: I actually am caching images exactly the way you're describing. I am already creating images using imagecreatetruecolor. I just tried using compressed .PNG's and my RAM usage became maxed out (from 2.5/4GB to 4/4GB) , the server speed decreased noticeably, and CPU usage went from around 10% to around 40%.  I do not want to use uncompressed PNG's as they are too large.

Comment: About 2 to 3 new images are processed every second. (That would be 10 - 20 without caching) I really need to stick with JPEG at this point.

Comment: How often does the url change? Aside from the imagecopymerge option, I think I am at the end of my help without being there to test stuff.

Comment: There are about 1200 different images with different URL's. Each one of them changes URL's every 8 to 10 minutes. (All at random points, not 1200 every ten minutes, more like 120 per minute, 2 per second.) Thanks for all your help, it just seems that in my situation changing the format isn't going to work

Answer (score 1):

You are drawing red text on a green background. This is a terrible idea, unless you really do want to make it illegible to [about 10% of the male population](http://extolerant.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/15-facts-on-color-blindness/). Please stop whatever you're doing and read up on [web accessibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility) before continuing.

The blurriness you're experiencing at the moment is a direct result of the JPEG compression. Here's why:

The human eye is more sensitive to changes of brightness than to changes of colour. This is because the human eye contains far more rod cells than cone cells. JPEG compression uses [chroma subsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) to take advantage of this fact. Typically, the chrominance (colour) information is encoded at half the horizontal and half the vertical resolution compared with the luminance (brightness).

Your red text has almost exactly the same brightness as the green background that you placed it on, so you are having to rely entirely on the low-resolution chrominance information in order to read it.

What you need to do is choose a better colour. Or better still, draw a black rectangle on the image, and put your text on top of that (using a light colour like white or yellow, not red).

But please do read up on web accessibility before doing anything.

Comment: Thanks for the scientific answer! I know it's a horrible design, right now I'm only testing the text. I will try adding a black rectangle with white text